# getElementById FirstChild throws Run Time Error 91

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the MSXML2 class to login to a website and download prices to my spreadsheet. I have a list of product numbers that the code uses to search the product and then it's supposed to pull the price element from the html.

My problem is that I keep getting an "Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set" error, and no amount of forum-diving has given me a solution.

The error occurs at `document.getElementById("prix").FirstChild.innerHTML = .responseText`

```
    Option Explicit

Function loginRematek()

 Dim XMLHttpRequest As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
 Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
 Dim cell As Integer
 Dim ItemNbr As String
 Dim document As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    'Login to Rematek
  With XMLHttpRequest
   .Open "POST", "https://rematek-energie.com/eng/customer-login/account- authentication.php", False
   .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   .send "name_se_connecter=se_connecter&zebra_honeypot_se_connecter=&courriel=rob@solacity.com&motpasse=password&connexion=Sign in"
  End With

  Debug.Print XMLHttpRequest.responseText

    'Get Element
  Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

  For cell = 1 To 38

      ItemNbr = Cells(cell, 1).Value

      With xhr

          .Open "GET", "https://rematek-energie.com/eng/pg/1/r/" & ItemNbr, False
          .send

          If .readyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
              Set document = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
              document.getElementById("prix").FirstChild.innerHTML = .responseText
          Else
              MsgBox "Error" & vbNewLine & "Ready state: " & .readyState & _
              vbNewLine & "HTTP request status: " & .Status
          End If

      Cells(cell, 2).Value = .responseText

      End With

    Next cell
End Function
```

Again, the error occurs at `document.getElementById("prix").FirstChild.innerHTML = .responseText`

The HTML I am trying to target is the `panier_prix_326` value, but the ID changes on every page, and as I'm targeting multiple pages I thought it would be better to target first the constant `prix` and then the first child of that element.

```
<tr>
    <td id="col-action">
        <div class="prix">
            <span id="panier_prix_326">99.40</span>
            <div id="prix-detail">MSRP: 152.93$</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `document`  is a new empty document. it cannot possibly contain an element with an id in it. `document.getElementById("prix")` will always be `nothing`

Comment: Ok, I see that now.. How can I fix this to target the element in the page's HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set document = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
document.getElementById("prix").FirstChild.innerHTML = .responseText
```

`document` is an empty HTML document - there is no content to select.

Possibly this is what you wanted:

```
If .readyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
    Set document = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    document.body.innerHTML = .responseText 
    Cells(cell, 2).Value = _
                  document.getElementById("prix").FirstChild.innerHTML
Else
    MsgBox "Error" & vbNewLine & "Ready state: " & .readyState & _
            vbNewLine & "HTTP request status: " & .Status
End If
```

**EDIT** - your HTML does not have an id "prix" so you can't use `getElementById` here.

```
<tr>
    <td id="col-action">
        <div class="prix">
            <span id="panier_prix_326">99.40</span>
            <div id="prix-detail">MSRP: 152.93$</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Maybe instead:

```
Cells(cell, 2).Value = _
 document.getElementById("col-action").getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
```

Comment: I tried this in place of what I have, but `document.innerHTML = .responseText` is giving me an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error

Comment: Try `document.body.innerHTML`

Comment: That solved that problem, but now `Cells(cell, 2).Value = document.getElementById("prix").FirstChild.innerHTML` is giving the first error ("Object variable or With block variable not set") again

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant HTML ?

Comment: Of course, sorry I meant to put that in when I initially posted

Comment: I can't believe I didn't catch that! Thank you so much, using that line of code makes it run perfectly